# How can I support jpa database serialization of a class who's source code I don't own?

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

If I have an entity I want to persist to a database in JPA2 I just add the @Entity annotation, as well as any other ones that specify its relationship, and such.

I have several classes that are from dependencies I do not own, that I would like to do this with. I was thinking of some ideas, but I'm not super happy with any of them.

1. Make an "empty" subclass that just delegates calls of everything to the real class. The empty subclass would be the ones holding the configuration annotations. I'm not sure this would work though because I think you need to add an annotation to the superclass.
2. Use an attribute-converter. This works OKay if I don't care about using that entity I've imported for a relationship. I'm already doing this now for some enums.
3. I guess I could configure it with the `persistence.xml`? But I'd like to avoid this at all costs.

Just to give another example of what I'm trying to do, in Spring you generally configure beans by putting @Componeont on them, and decorating the class with other JPA annotations. If, however, you don't own the class, Spring has a simple mechanism with the @Bean annotation, where you create and configure the class inside of a method that the @Configuration class calls to get a reference to that entity. This way you can use third party libraries as beans without having access to the source code.

Comment: How did this get a close vote for "too broad". It's a very specific question about how to handle a case that doesn't seem well supported by JPA2 since it went all annotation driven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using orm.xml to give JPA mappings to java classes I don't control the source code for.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, whether you own the class you want to persist or not, you should never annotate your business entity with `@Entity`. The rational behind this is quite simple: the database is an I/O channel. The I/O channel is a detail. Your business logic should be independent from details.

You should map the business entity to a DTO, which is passed to the DAO, which THEN maps it to a database entity and persist it. Don't trust me on this one, [this opinion actually stems from uncle Bob](https://youtu.be/o_TH-Y78tt4?t=2743).

So the answer is: transform the entity into a DTO, pass this DTO to the corresponding DAO, which transforms it again into some database object and persists it.

Comment: Everyone's got their own opinion on this. I think DTAs and DTOs are trash data patterns leftover from JEE hell. I also use open entitymanager in view which has been declared an "anti-pattern" for some reason. Oh lordy my transaction stays open slightly longer during serialization. Someone get the vapors, I'm passing out.